# Handling large numbers in PHP

Tags: php, types, int

After a couple of minutes i've realize the bug that i was having: the magic `2147483647` number, that upper limit for `integer` type on PHP/32. I need to manage biggers number in my function:

```
public function albumExists($name) // e.g. 104112826372452
{
   $albums = $this->getAlbums();

   // If $name is int, search the key in $albums
   if(is_int($name) && ($found = array_key_exists($id = intval($name), $albums)))
      return ($found ? $id : false);

   // Start looking for $name as string
   foreach($album as $id => $a) if ($a->name == $name) return intval($id);

   return false; // Found nothing
}
```

in order to give the ability to search both by `id` and `name`. But `intval()` will always return the upper limit. How can handle quite big numbers like, say, `104112826372452`? Ideas?

**EDIT**: usage example:

```
$album = $fb->createAlbum('Test Album'); // Will return album id
// The use albumExists to check if id exists
$photo1 = $fb->uploadPhoto('mypic1.png', null, $album); 
$photo2 = $fb->uploadPhoto('mypic2.png', null, 'Test Album'); // find or create
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're converting to an int for sanity purposes (so it appears), perhaps you could just adjust it to evaluate it purely on it's numeric basis instead of int datatype:

```
if(ctype_digit($name) && ($found = array_key_exists($id = $name, $albums)))
      return ($found ? $id : false);
//etc
```

Actually, should this work too?

```
if(ctype_digit($name) && ($found = array_key_exists($name, $albums)))
      return ($found ? $name: false);
//etc
```

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can use the [`gmp`](http://php.net/gmp) or [`bcmath`](http://php.net/bcmath) functions for that.

It's not quite clear why you insist on casting to PHP integers. Just leave your database numbering as strings, when don't need to calculate with them. Not everything that looks like a number needs to be represented as number.

I guess your real problem is the differentation with `is_int()`. Just use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) in its place, which works with arbitrary-length numeric strings and does not depend on integer-casted values.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` has an upper limit, and bigger *numbers* will be represented as `floats`, which are imprecise and therefore a bad idea to use in this situation. Use a `string` to store such numbers and the [BC Math](http://php.net/bc) extension if you need to do calculations on it.

Comment: But using a `string ` i will not able to provide seach both by id and name... am i right?

Comment: Because i can pass either an album name or an id to that function. Passing both as a string i'll not able to discriminate on how search for.

Comment: @Gremo You can still check if the name contains only digits, or you could make the API less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Unfornuately PHP *int* type can only go upto 2147483647 but PHP *float*  can hold integers upto 10000000000000

Check out php.net 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

**UPDATE**

PHP.net says that a *float* can accurately hold an *integer* upto 10000000000000. Im not sure if *float* has an upper limit though.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run PHP on a `64bit` OS as the in size is determined by the underlying operating system. This is obviously dependent if you can get access to `64bit` hardware, one thing to note is that this will be faster than using `gmp`/`bcmath` but unless pure speed is your aim it probably won't be an issue for you